# Can anonymous and authenticated profiles coexist together in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net-membership, asp.net-profiles

I'm trying to figure out exactly when the event `Profile_MigrateAnonymous` fires.

My best guess from just tracing through my code is that it fires when it detects BOTH an anonymous membership cookie AND an authenticated membership cookie. Can anyone confirm this? I'm looking for real in depth answer here. Not just it gets called 'when a user logs in'.

Now - why do I care?

I was trying to keep the anonymous profile hanging around after a user had authenticated so that once they log out I'd still be able to tell who they were, and certain settings that may have been set.

The problem I'm seeing is that Profile_MigrateAnonymous is getting fired on EVERY request. Not just when a user has logged in. This makes me believe it to be a bad practice to keep the anonymous cookie hanging around - and that I should always call [ClearAnonymousIdentifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556483)();

For instance I have a new store and an old store. I want users that have access to the 'new store' to never be put back on the old store. Obviously - as with most shopping carts you don't need to autenticate to begin a session. Therefore I think the only way is to call 'ClearAnonymousIdentifier' as designed but keep a secondary cookie 'UseNewStore' to track which store they should go to.

is this a good interpretation. Or should I just not care that Profile_MigrateAnonymous is being called all the time?

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother with it. There is a simpler way

Migrating Profile Properties During Log On

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/taab950e.aspx